# Is using while loop in Java unsafe?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, cpu-usage

I heard that loops in Java take maximum CPU power to run as fast as possible.

Is it unsafe to use while loops that run for a long time?

I know that it is safe in threads if I sleep the thread for a little time.

But are fast long-lasting loops that are not inside a sleeping thread-safe?

Comment: By "unsave" and "save", do you mean "unsafe" and "safe"?

Comment: I think its save to say that was OP's intention

Comment: I'm curious, what makes you think they might be unsafe and what kind of dangers do you expect?

Comment: I'm not really worried about anything. I only want to optimize my software as good as possible. And in order to do this I have to know this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Software

No, not really. As long as you don't cause issues with held locks deadlocking other parts of code and you have valid stopping conditions so the user doesn't *need* to kill your application you should be fine. ***However***, if you are creating new objects and hold references to them you could run out of memory.

#### Hardware:

Many programs, including Java, have their fair share of CPU use and loops. Games, other compilers, and even office applications can do this. In fact, many programs rely on infinite loops(albeit with a stopping condition but they can be of the `while(true)` type. Heat can be generated but it's nothing to worry about.

Comment: @delnan edits committed. I unfortunately have the tendency of posting and finishing up in an edit.

Answer (score 2):

Long running loops inside a thread which are not calling blocking code will use high CPU.

They are safe because they won't cause your software to crash, but should probably be avoided as they will cause the user's PC to perform poorly. No one enjoys an application which uses an entire core unnecessarily.

The only time you should not be blocking threads in long running loops is when low latency is desired, and you have no other solution.

Hardware-wise the only danger you face is from overheating. If you're not selling hardware to the user, this can't really be handled, so don't worry about hardware damage from looping quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I have run thread busy waiting for years, on an over clocked CPU.  As long as you have a decent cooling system and do run all you cores this way, it shouldn't overheat.

I design systems to have one or two threads which deliberately busy wait all the time and never block or sleep, to minimise latency.

Answer (score 1):

It is best practice to not leave a thread looping if it doesn't have to be. You can use Wait and Notify (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html), or a Condition to avoid leaving a thread in a loop unnecessarily. That said, if the loop is doing work the whole time, I wouldn't see a problem with it.