# Is it dangerous to use while to pause the entire java program?

Tags: java, loops

Ok, I'm pretty new to java programming, but I really need to pause program execution until some event happens:

```
while(!isItHappened());
doSomethingAfterItHappend();
```

What is the best way to avoid this ugly situation?

Comment: Depends on the case. In background threads for example, that's usually fine. You can use listener pattern to avoid this.

Comment: @Bubletan that piece of code is inside some event listener.

Comment: Then you shouldn't do it like this. Event dispatcher thread will be blocked.

Comment: This is what is known as "busy waiting".

Comment: See also [Is using while loop in Java unsafe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261696/is-using-while-loop-in-java-unsafe).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really dangerous (thanks to preemptive multitasking), but a waste of resources. Use a [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) with a count of 1, like `startSignal` in the example. Or dig deeper and implement your own waiting mechanics using `Object`'s `wait` and `notify` / `notifyAll` methods.

Comment: Ok, I'll try CountDownLatch and give you a feedback. Sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: I used wait and notify, now my code is look like this:
`syncronized(itHappened) {
itHappened.wait();
doSomethingAfterItHappend();
}`
Is it better? Isn't it "busy waiting"?

Comment: @J.Leeroy Using while is busy waiting.

Answer (score 3):

I compared CPU usage.

1. CPU usage 13-15%:

   ```
   while(!isItHappened());
   doSomethingAfterItHappend();
   ```
2. CPU usage well 0-1%:

   ```
   synchronized(itHappend) {
       itHappened.wait();   
   }
   doSomething();
   ```

So second piece of code is obviously better. Many thanks to duckstep.